# regex non greedy quantifier catching nothing, greedy catching too much

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a python regex formula that parses the content of a heading, however the greedy quantifier is not working well, and the non greedy quantifier is not working at all.

My string is

```
Step 1 Introduce The Assets:
Step2 Verifying the Assets
Step 3Making sure all the data is in the right place:
```

What I'm trying to do is extract the step number, and the heading, excluding the `:`.
Now I've tried multiple regex string and came up with these 2:

```
r1 = r"Step ?([0-9]+) ?(.*) ?:?"
r2 = r"Step ?([0-9]+) ?(.*?) ?:?"
```

r1 is capturing the step number, but is also capturing `:` at the end.
r2 is capturing the step number, and `''`. I'm not sure how to handle the case where there is a `.*` followed by a string.

Necessary Edit:
The heading might contain `:` inside the string, I just want to ignore the trailing one. I know I can `strip(':')` but I want to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: With multiline mode you can try `r2 = r"Step ?([0-9]+) ?(.*?) ?:?$"` (append `$`). Without it, you allow the match to not contain the whole line, which allows non-greedy quantifier to match nothing.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks, I understand from this that the entire regex will have to match until the end, hence a greedy quantifier will be forced to find the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the pattern using a negated character class without the non greedy and optional parts using a negated character class:

```
\bStep ?(\d+) ?([^:\n]+)
```

- `\bStep ?` Match the word `Step` and optional space
- `(\d+) ?` Capture 1+ digits in **group 1** followed by matching an optional space
- `([^:\n]+)` Capture 1+ chars other than `:` or a newline in **group 2**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pLtNW9/1)

If the colon has to be at the end of the string:

```
\bStep ?(\d+) ?([^:\n]+):?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ITvATl/1)